# Customize function placing in linker script

Tags: c, ld, linker-scripts

## Motivation

I'm learning how to use and write my own linker scripts.

## The problem

Currently, I have 2 simple functions in a `.c` file and I'd like to put each of those functions in separate sections, but I couldn't found out how to "access" those functions in the linker script.

## Reproduction steps

Those two files are all in the same directory:

`file1.c`

```c
int func1() {
    return 10;
}

char * func3() {
    return (void *) 0;
}
```

`linker.ld`

```
SECTIONS {
    .text 0xDEADBEEF : {
        file1.o (.text.func1)
    }

    .data 0x4 : {
        file1.o (.text.func3)
    }
}
```

Now do the following:

```
gcc -c file1.c
ld -T linker.ld file1.o
```

### Expected/Desired output

What I expect to get from `objdump -d a.out`:

```
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000deadbeef <func1>:
    deadbeef:   55                      push   %rbp
    deadbef0:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    deadbef3:   b8 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%eax
    deadbef8:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    deadbef9:   c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000004 <func3>:
    deadbefa:   55                      push   %rbp
    deadbefb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    deadbefe:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    deadbf03:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    deadbf04:   c3                      ret
```

Or if it's possible I'd like to have those functions in custom-named sections like `customSection1` and `customSection2`.

### What I got

I got the following from `objdump -d a.out`:

```
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000deadbeef <func1>:
    deadbeef:   55                      push   %rbp
    deadbef0:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    deadbef3:   b8 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%eax
    deadbef8:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    deadbef9:   c3                      ret    

00000000deadbefa <func3>:
    deadbefa:   55                      push   %rbp
    deadbefb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    deadbefe:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    deadbf03:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    deadbf04:   c3                      ret
```

## Other information

- I'm aware that the names in the brackets of `<filename> (<here>)` should be sections, not function names. However, I thought that `<section>.<function>` could work, which does not work, as you can see
- I don't know if it's uncommon to put code into the `.data` section. I just read [in the `ld` manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html#SEC18) that `a.out` supports only the section names, `.text`, `.bss` and `.data`:

> In formats which only support a limited number of sections, such as a.out, the name must be one of the names supported by the format (a.out, for example, allows only .text, .data or .bss).

So I chose `.data`.

Comment: You need to compile with `-ffunction-sections` in order the compiler to place each function into it's own section

Comment: Oh nice! Thank you :) Could you write your comment as an answer please? So I can tick this question as answered.

Comment: @EugeneSh. please write a short answer, so I can tick this question as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to instruct the compiler to place each function in a separate section (named as you would expect `.text.<function_name>` or similar) you need compile with the `-ffunction-sections` option (for GCC).
See the documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

Comment: Complementary documentation for the section management in the .ld script
https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html#SEC17